# Howto Disable smooth image on OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

I'm trying to view an image on a map using OpenLayer, my image is a PNG that follows the SRID:4326. I setup an OpenLayers map and I set the projection information in order to re-project my image in OpenLayer SRID (3857).

Now..my problem is that OpenLayer shows my classified PNG with smoothed colors. I need to view the PNG without smoothed color render.

Actually my OpenLayers map shows this image
[image]

but I need to view my image with no smoothed colors.

[image]

Any idea?

UPDATE: If I disable the smoothing option, following below answers, output image will be rendered without smoothing... but there are some pixels that are rendered with wrong color (with a lighter shader or with less opacity)

this is the output image:

[image]

but the output should be :

[image]

Comment: guess it's like cached data from higer zoom. which displays when there's no matched images.

Comment: mmm I don't think so... If I perform a higher zoom , image is still smoothed. Maybe the problem is the reproject procedure that includes errors when it tries to recreate the reprojected image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question now, but I've been wrestling this for a couple of hours and have finally made it work, so I thought others might find this helpful.

Since OpenLayers [6.4.0](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.4.0), you can disable image smoothing for a source (code sample below is from [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/disable-image-smoothing.html) on the OpenLayers website):

```
var disabledLayer = new TileLayer({
  // specify className so forEachLayerAtPixel can distinguish layers
  className: 'ol-layer-dem',
  source: new XYZ({
    attributions: attributions,
    url:
      'https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/terrain-rgb/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=' + key,
    maxZoom: 10,
    crossOrigin: '',
    imageSmoothing: false,
  }),
});
```

Note: Make sure you set `imageSmoothing: false` on the **source**, not the layer! It won't cause any errors if you set it on the layer, but it just won't achieve anything ;)

I've found that if I want the pixelation to work the way I expect it to, I need to set `imageSmoothing: false` on the source, then set `maxZoom` on the source to be less than what I've set as `maxZoom` on the layer and the view (e.g. `maxZoom: 14` on the source, and `maxZoom: 19` on the layer and the view). Then I get the nice solid blocky pixels I want, without any distortion or shading or incorrect values inside any pixels.

Finally, make sure that the `maxZoom` setting on your layer is the same as the `maxZoom` setting on your view, or your user will be able to zoom in too far and your layer will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not on ol but on the HTML5 Canvas rendering. You have to turn off the image smoothing on the map canvas. Look at the [imageSmoothingEnabled option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled).

Using Openlayers you can use precompose/postcompose events to disable it for your layer only:

```
// Remove image smoothing on precompose
layer.on('precompose', function(event) {
  var ctx = event.context;
  ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = 
  ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = 
  ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = 
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
}
// Restore image smoothing on postcompose
layer.on('postcompose', function(event) {
  var ctx = event.context;
  ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = 
  ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = 
  ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = 
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
}
```

NB: it is navigator dependent...

Comment: Thank you for answer, last Friday I found a solution similar to your suggestion:   map.on('precompose', function(evt) {
        evt.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        evt.context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        evt.context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        evt.context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    });

Comment: Hi, I wrote an update of my issue. Unfortunately, if I disable imageSmoothing of Canvax my problem will not be resolved... any suggestion? :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer above resolves my issue. But I found also this solution

```
  map.on('precompose', function(evt) {
    evt.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    evt.context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    evt.context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    evt.context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
});
```

With this code I was able to disable smoothing for every layer on my OL map.